# Set Theory: How do I typeset domain/range subtractions (anti-restrictions)?

Tags: math-operators

I'm using `\triangleright` and `\triangleleft` to typeset restrictions, but I can't find the symbols for subtractions, which are the same triangles, but with a horizontal line in the middle. For example:

[image: Domain substraction]

Comment: I was ready to tell you that I did not found something like this and to ask you if you would like to create one for you in tikz... Then I show that you use MathJax... And I have to tell you that it makes difference and thus your question it is probably out of this site scope. MathJax is not LaTeX and is not supported here. But you can leave the question open by removing the MathJax stuff to let other people get help on this specific problem... (in LaTeX and friends.. MathJax is not between friends... may be is an enemy :P )

Comment: Oh, I see. I will make such edition. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you are welcome... And  I still looking for it... I found that it exists somewhere and may be works in MathJax too... If I find something I will answer...

Comment: I found that there is a $\dsub$ and $\rsub$ commands in oz package that are defined as $\ndres$ ans $\nrres$... Try them.. May be you are lucky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by koleygr, the `stix` package includes this symbol. However, including that package changes much of the appearance of math throughout the document.

A different option is to use `\ooalign` to overlay a scaled `-` with the built-in `\triangleright` and `\triangleleft` commands.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\rsubt}{\mathrel{%
    \ooalign{$\triangleright$\cr\hidewidth\scalebox{.65}[1]{$-$}\hidewidth\cr}%
    }}
\newcommand{\dsubt}{\mathrel{%
    \ooalign{$\triangleleft$\cr\hidewidth\scalebox{.65}[1]{$-$}\hidewidth\cr}%
    }}

\begin{document}

\[
A\dsubt R\quad A\rsubt R
\]

\end{document}
```

If you use a different math font, you may need to adjust the `.65` in the `\scalebox`.

A more complicated version with `\mathpalette` allows the symbol to appear in a subscript:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\domsub}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\dom@sub\relax}}
\newcommand{\dom@sub}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\triangleright$\cr
    \hidewidth$\m@th#1\text{\scalebox{.65}[1]{$-$}}$\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
\newcommand{\ransub}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\ran@sub\relax}}
\newcommand{\ran@sub}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\triangleleft$\cr
    \hidewidth$\m@th#1\text{\scalebox{.65}[1]{$-$}}$\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
A\ransub R_{A\ransub R}\quad A\domsub R_{A\domsub R}
\]

\end{document}
```

Egreg has used this type of code frequently on this site to create new symbols. That's where I learned the technique.

Answer (score 1):

The package `oz` offers such symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{oz}


\begin{document}
\string\dsub{} gives $\dsub$

\string\rsub{} gives $\rsub$

\string\ndres{} gives $\ndres$ 

\string\nrres{} gives $\nrres$

\end{document}
```

Also `\dsub` and `\rsub` are provided by `stix` package... (And may be more)

[image]